# google_spreadsheet: query from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to run this command

```
=QUERY( ImportRange( "1GPxWbG1B8WWXWgam-qJXstDCZ_TB0btQwTxwt9iaa8A" , 
"C_Detailed" ) , "select B where  A = '"&Sheet3!$A$2&"'")
```

But I get an Error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   NO_COLUMNB

I also tried to call it as the column title (date), but it has no effect.

I can't use vlookup because I have to check the equality between dates.
As for it- how do I check equality between dates of format `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been reading multiple websites, and I have discovered that if you are using the new Google Sheets, you must use the entire link when you are calling for the URL in the first part of your formula. Also, you may want to make your spreadsheet so that people trying to help you can view the document. You can do this by going into sharing settings > advanced > Click Change (where it says specific people can access) > change to people anywhere on the web can find and view.